# Find row-wise combinations of a 2 dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, concatenation, combinations

I have a matrix:

```
X = [2,6,1; 3,8,1; 4,7,1; 6,2,1; 6,4,1; 7,3,1; 8,5,1; 7,6,1];
```

I want to find all row-wise combinations of X. i.e.

```
A(1) = [2, 6, 1; 3, 8, 1; 4, 7, 1]
A(2) = [2, 6, 1; 3, 8, 1; 6, 2, 1]
:
:
:
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
X = [2,6,1; 3,8,1; 4,7,1; 6,2,1; 6,4,1; 7,3,1; 8,5,1; 7,6,1];
p = 3
[m, n] = size(X);
comb = combnk(1:m, p);
[s, t] = size(comb);
c = [X(comb(:,1), :, :) X(comb(:,2), :, :) X(comb(:,3), :, :)];
```

This gives me a matrix like:

```
c = 2     6     1     3     8     1     4     7     1
    2     6     1     3     8     1     6     2     1
    2     6     1     3     8     1     6     4     1
```

I want to apply the concatenate matrix option to obtain c to make it dynamic depending on value of p but I'm not sure how to use it. I don't want to use For loops. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you not mean `c = [X(comb(1,:), :, :)...` above?

Comment: Also your title says 3D matrix but your example is 2D...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fully vectorized, so it should be fast:

```
n = 3; %// number of rows to pick each time
ind = reshape(nchoosek(1:size(X,1), n).', [], 1); %'// indices of combinations
A = permute(reshape(X(ind,:).', size(X,2), n, []), [2 1 3]);
```

The result is

```
A(:,:,1)
ans =
     2     6     1
     3     8     1
     4     7     1

A(:,:,2)
ans =
     2     6     1
     3     8     1
     6     2     1
```

etc.

Should you need the result in the form of a cell array, you can convert `A` from 3D-array to cell array this way:

```
A = mat2cell(A, size(A,1), size(A,2), ones(1,size(A,3)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking is pretty close. This code does the job. I put comments in code, which should be easy to read.

```
X = [2,6,1; 3,8,1; 4,7,1; 6,2,1; 6,4,1; 7,3,1; 8,5,1; 7,6,1];
p = 3;
%// List all combinations choosing 3 out of 1:8.
v = nchoosek(1:size(X,1), p);
%// Use each row of v to create the matrices, and put the results in an cell array.
%// This is the A matrix in your question.
A = arrayfun(@(k)X(v(k,:), :), 1:size(v,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
%// And you can concatenate A vertically to get c.
flatA = cellfun(@(x)reshape(x, 1, []), A, 'UniformOutput', false);
c = vertcat(flatA{:});
```

PS: From my understanding I thought the result you wanted was **A**, which is an easy to use cell array. But I added an extra step to get **c** exactly as in your question just in case.

Disclaimer: arrayfun and cellfun are pretty much equivalent to for loop in terms of performance.

Comment: Agreed - this code does not "do the job without a loop" because `arrayfun` and now `cellfun` are both just loops with extra overhead. -1 until you remove the line that says "without loop"

Comment: Removed as adviced. I wasn't trying to be deceptive. Many times people ask for "without loop" just because one-liner looks nice :)

Comment: @xmo -1 removed but in that case you should add a disclaimer that there are loops under hood rather than saying without loops. I would still add such a disclaimer in your answer if it was mine

Comment: I was not aware of this fact.

Comment: Disclaimer added. If performance is a concern, Luis's answer should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `reshape` and a bunch of transposes since Matlab is column-[major ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order):

```
c = reshape(X(comb',:)',9,[])'
```

or if you want a 3D matrix:

```
A = permute(reshape(X(comb',:)',3,3,[])', [2,1,3])
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for pointing out my error in question. I've changed that. The code works correctly, but what I want is: A(1) = [2, 6, 1; 3, 8, 1; 4, 7, 1] while this returns [2 6 1 3 8 1 4 7 1]

Comment: It might be a stupid question but I tried a lot still wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Both are fine but A(1) is preferable.

Comment: @Learner23 I strongly disagree, I think you'll find that a 3D numerical matrix is far easier to work with than a cell array when the dimensions allow it (which they do in your case)